# Where can I have my programming blog post validated?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I wrote a blog on core computer science concepts or about programming and want to validate it to be absolutely sure that what I have written, read or understood is correct.

Are such posts allowed on Stack Overflow or the Programmers SE?

Comment: Nice that you have asked on Meta before posting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, I would not do that. "Proofread my blog" is not a valid question.

If there is a topic-related chat, you could perhaps ask the people there if they would be interested in having a look and providing some feedback. You could then point them to the relevant blog post. Don't go spamming your blog in a chat either though. Ask first.

**Note:**
The only exception I can think of (though it's a tricky one) is in the research process for your blog post. If you are trying to treat an abstract concept and are unsure yourself, you might be able to formulate a valid question and ask for help/explanation. You could then take what you've learned and use that for your blog. You might want to consider proper attribution in that case though.

But don't post your blog-post here (SO or the Programmers SE) to have us  check it for you.

Comment: @Bart you have a good point of trying to come up with the valid question

Comment: @mazhar, for the next time, you can ask the question for a topic you're going to blog and from the answer(s) make a post. It will save you a time...

Comment: @TLama well the problem here is that i don't care about my blog post but for the validation of the knowledge which i have clearly mention in the question :).

Comment: @mazhar, sorry, misread that. Taking back my comments...